# iusuarioRepository in com.portfolio.LucasMorales.Security.Service.UsuarioService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java

soy nuevo usando Java y estoy haciendo un proyecto, pero cuando quiero hacer un run file sobre mi application.java me salta este error. No se si es necesario que suba algun otro codigo o foto, cualquier cosa quedo pendiente al post.

- Mensaje de Error

  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
  2023-05-09 19:37:35.470 ERROR 1656 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

  ```
   ***************************
   APPLICATION FAILED TO START
   ***************************

   Description:

   Field iusuarioRepository in com.portfolio.LucasMorales.Security.Service.UsuarioService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

   The injection point has the following annotations:
       - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


   Action:

   Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
  ```
- UsuarioService.java

  @Service

  ```
   @Transactional
   public class UsuarioService {

   @Autowired
   iUsuarioRepository iusuarioRepository;

   public Optional<User> getByUserName(String username) {

       return iusuarioRepository.findByUsername(username);
   }

   public boolean existsByName(String username) {

       return iusuarioRepository.existsByName(username);
   }

   public boolean existsByMail(String mail) {

       return iusuarioRepository.existsByMail(mail);
   }

   public void save(User user){

       iusuarioRepository.save(user);
   }
  ```

  }
- UserDetailsImpl.java

  @Service

  ```
   @EnableJpaRepositories("com.portfolio.LucasMorales.Security.Service")
   @EntityScan(basePackages="UsuarioService")
   public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService{
       @Autowired 
       UsuarioService usuarioService;
       @Override
       public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
           User user = usuarioService.getByUserName(username).get();
           return Userprincipal.build(user);

       }

   }
  ```